# How to disable draggable property in Highchart for a single ponit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

In column highchart how to remove draggale property for a single point.

```
`series: [{
                      data: container,
                      showInLegend: true,
                      color: '#ADD8E6',
                      name: 'Onsite',
                      id: 'Onsite',
                      minPointLength: 3,
                      draggableY: true,
                      dragMinY: 0,
                      dragMaxY:100,
                      type: 'column',
                      events: {
                      }
                  }`
```

I want to remove draggable property for a single point and for the rest of the points I can drag Y axis

Comment: you can use this http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/2607/

Comment: You can simply set draggableY:false in your single dataPoint object. Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/3320/